# Gelfand space of a commutative unital Banach algebra is weak* compact

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology, gelfand-representation

Before I come to my actual questions, I want to give some context (e.g. definitions, ...).

(1) Let $X$ be a normed space over a field $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$. Then we define $ X' := \{ \varphi: X \to \mathbb{K} \ \text{is linear and continuous} \} $ which is called the *topological dual space* of $X$.

(2) On $X'$ we can define the *weak* topology* which is characterized as  the weakest topology on $X'$ which makes the functionals $ x': X' \to \mathbb{K},\ x'(\varphi):=\varphi(x) $ continuous (for all $x \in X$).

(3) *Alaoglu's theorem* shows that the closed unit ball $B_{X'} := \{\varphi \in X' : \lVert  \varphi \rVert \leq 1 \}$ is compact regarding the weak* topology. This is one of the great advantages of the weak* topology over the norm topology because otherwise the closed unit ball would be compact only in the finite-dimensional case.

(4) Now let $A$ be a commutative unital Banach algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Then we define
$$ \Gamma_A := \{\varphi:A\to \mathbb{C},\ \varphi \ \text{is linear and multiplicative with}\ \varphi(1_A) = 1 \} $$
which is called the *Gelfand space* of $A$. It is easy to show that $\Gamma_A \subset B_{A'}$.

---

**My goal:** I want to show that $\Gamma_A \subset A'$ is a (weak*-)compact Hausdorff space. (Later I want to show the *Gelfand-Naimark theorem* but  for now, this is enough).

I was able to show the Hausdorff part. For the compact part, I can use Alaoglu's theorem which leaves me with the task to show that $\Gamma_A$ is a (weak*-)closed subset of $A'$.

**Attempt 1**: My first naive approach to showing that $\Gamma_A$ is closed w.r.t. the weak* topology was to show that for a sequence $(\varphi_n) \subset \Gamma_A$ which converges to some $\varphi \in A'$ we already have $\varphi \in \Gamma_A$. But then I figured out that **this approach which works for metric spaces does not work for topological spaces**.

**Attempt 2**: Since I only have very rudimentary knowledge of topology, I tried to do this without sequences and in some textbook I found that you can write
$$
\Gamma_A := \bigcap_{x,y\in A} \{\varphi \in A' : \varphi(xy) = \varphi(x) \varphi(y) \} \cap \{\varphi: \varphi(1_A) = 1 \}.
$$
However, I can't figure out why those sets are closed under the weak* topology. Maybe I can use that the functions $x'$, $y'$ and $(xy)'$ are continuous? But then I would need that sums and scalar products of continuous functions are also continuous but I am not sure if this is true in this topological setting.

---

**Question:** Why is the Gelfand space $\Gamma_A$ closed with respect to the weak* topology?

It would be nice if the answer would need as little understanding of topological spaces as possible.

Comment: Attempt $1$ works immediately if you take the argument with sequences and replace every instance of "sequence" with "net" instead. Explicitely let $(\varphi_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be a net in $\Gamma_A$ and suppose $\varphi_\lambda\to\varphi$. Then $\varphi(ab)=\lim\varphi_\lambda(ab)=\lim\varphi_\lambda(a)\varphi_\lambda(b)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$, so $\varphi\in\Gamma_A$.

Comment: Also note that $\varphi(1) = 1$ is automatic when $\varphi \ne 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will go with the following solution:

We can write
\begin{align*}
\Gamma_A &= \bigcap_{x,y\in A} \{ \varphi \in A' : \varphi(xy) = \varphi(x) \varphi(y) \} \cap \{\varphi: \varphi(1_A) =1 \} \\
&= \bigcap_{x,y \in A} \{ \varphi \in A': (xy)'(\varphi) - x'(\varphi) y'(\varphi) = 0 \} \cap \{\varphi: 1_A'(\varphi)=1 \}.
\end{align*}

Now, notice that $x'$, $y'$, $(xy)'$ and $1_A'$ are (by definition) continuous functions from $A'$ to $\mathbb{K}$. Since
$$
+ : \mathbb{K} \times \mathbb{K} \to \mathbb{K},\ (x,y)\mapsto x+y \quad \text{and} \quad \cdot: \mathbb{K} \times \mathbb{K} \to \mathbb{K},\ (x,y)\mapsto x \cdot y
$$
are continuous functions, we know that $(xy)' - x' \cdot y'$ is also a continuous function.

Thus, $\Gamma_A$ is closed as the intersection of closed sets.